# Run jquery at the end of Ember.CollectionView rendering

Tags: ember.js

I have a **ContainerView** which contains a **CollectionView**. After this **CollectionView** renders on the screen I *need to perform a jquery function* which essentially looks through the content of the rendered template and performs some display modifications.

If I perform that jquery within the **didInsertElement** of **CollectionView** it works but it gets executed for every single element in the **CollectionView** where as I really just need it to be done once at the end. How do I specify that?

http://jsfiddle.net/JFqNr/ (note doesn't render on jsfiddle or some reason but just to show you structure)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.FooContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    childViews: ['elementList'],    

    elementList: Ember.CollectionView.extend({
        content: function() {
            return [
                { Title: "Dashboard", ID: "dashboard" },
                { Title: "Invoices", ID: "invoices" },
                { Title: "Expenses", ID: "expenses" },
                { Title: "People", ID: "people" },
                { Title: "Reports", ID: "reports" },
                { Title: "Settings", ID: "settings" }
            ];
        }.property(),        
       template: Ember.Handlebars.compile( '{{view.content.title}}' ),

       didInsertElement: function() {
             // perform jquery function            
       }
    }),

   didInsertElement: function() {
         // does not work if perforemed here
   }    
});

App.initialize();
​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality to do this has only very recently been added to the master branch, so you will need to be compile your own version of Ember.
You can now schedule into an `afterRender` queue to run after all the individual views have been rendered.

```
App.FooContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  // Existing code
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
      // perform jQuery function here;
    });
 }
```

See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1528 for code details.

Comment: this is very useful, and most likely will fix a problem I have right now when using `Ember.run.next()` to execute code against dom elements. @Bradley, do you have any projections when this code will end up in ember-latest?