# Ember.js and Bootstrap accordion effect

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am trying to use the [bootstrap accordion component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) in my Ember.js project. I've looked at many solutions including:

1. [ember.js and bootstrap accordion - the "ember way" of creating the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362405/ember-js-and-bootstrap-accordion-the-ember-way-of-creating-the-view)
2. http://indexiatech.github.io/ember-components/
3. and http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/

The first link seems a bit dated but provided some useful information. The second link actually has a working accordion component but I don't want to include everything else. The final link has many components but the accordion component. So, I decided to quickly implement one of my own:

In my template:

```
<div class="cw-filter-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">

                {{#accordion-panel data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-href="#collapseOne" data-aria-expanded="true" data-aria-controls="collapseOne"}}
                    Search Filters:
                {{/accordion-panel}}
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <!--Whatever needs to be displayed in collapsible panel goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component markup:

```
<div role="button" data-toggle="{{data-toggle}}" data-parent="{{data-parent}}" aria-expanded="{{data-aria-expanded}}" aria-controls="{{data-aria-controls}}" {{action "toggleCollapse"}}>
    {{yield}}
</div>
```

And component javascript:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        toggleCollapse: function() {
            Ember.$(this.get('data-parent') ).find(this.get('data-href')).slideToggle();
            this.toggleProperty('data-aria-expanded');
        }
    }
});
```

This works, however, I was wondering if there is a better 'Ember' way of achieving this?