# How to catch whether array was inserted in handlebar in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I hope this is not duplicate question, but I am not able to find solution...

I have Jobs and Users, one user has many jobs:

```
JP.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    jobs: DS.hasMany("JP.Job")
});
```

I am inserting data in user_dashboard.handlebar:

```
 {{#each job in jobs}}
      <li>
         {{job.shortDescription}}<br />
         {{job.startsAt}}</li>
    {{/each}}
```

This is my route:

```
JP.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('users',  JP.User.find());
 }
});
```

How can I catch event after all jobs for user are inserted into the handlebar? I have tried different ways to catch it (`controller.jobs.isLoaded, content.isLoaded, didInsertElement`...), but it didn't work.

I can try to catch insertion of each job, but I think there must be some better way to catch insertion of jobs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `afterRender` queue, check out [Run jquery at the end of Ember.CollectionView rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538021/run-jquery-at-the-end-of-ember-collectionview-rendering/13539379#13539379) for a duplicate question