# Access DOM elements of asynchronously loaded and rendered data (Ember)

Tags: jquery, ember.js, render

In my ember application I use asynchronously loaded data (using ember data and the rest-adapter) to be displayed with handlebars. After the data is loaded and and rendered I want to manipulate how these data are presented (calculate position where they are located). This needs to be done on viewport resize as well.

At the moment I'm trying to get this working with the approaches suggested in
[How to catch whether array was inserted in handlebar in Ember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874812/how-to-catch-whether-array-was-inserted-in-handlebar-in-ember) 
and
[Run jquery at the end of Ember.CollectionView rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538021/run-jquery-at-the-end-of-ember-collectionview-rendering/13539379#13539379) .
I even tried to use schedule instead of scheduleOnce resulting in calling my display update method only once and still, the asynchronous loaded data are not rendered and the method does not call again after the data are loaded and rendered.

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
templateName: 'calendar',
didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    this.$('#calender_button_new').click(function(){
        document.location.href= "index.html#/add-appointment/select-employee";
    });
    this.$('#calender_button_home').click(function(){
        document.location.href= "index.html#/home";
    });
},

updateCalendar: function() {
    console.log(this.$('.appointment').length);
    var view = this;
    this.$('.appointment').each(function(index, item){
        var id = $(item).attr('data-appointment');
        view.controller.store.find('appointment', id).then(function(appointment){
            var beginning_base = Math.floor(appointment.get('beginning'));
            var end_base = Math.floor(appointment.get('end'));
            // get cell where appointment starts, each cell can be identified by the attributes data-time and data-employee
            var beginning_block = $('td[data-employee="' + appointment.get('doneBy').get('id') + '"][data-time="' + beginning_base + '"]');
            var end_block = $('td[data-employee="' + appointment.get('doneBy').get('id') + '"][data-time="' + end_base + '"]');
            // calculate exact position in the cell when the appointment starts, one cell covers an hour but the appointment might not start at full hour
            var beginning_offset = beginning_block.outerHeight()*(appointment.get('beginning')-beginning_base);
            var end_offset = end_block.outerHeight()*(appointment.get('end')-end_base);
            $(item).css({top:beginning_block.offset().top+beginning_offset-59, 
                        left:beginning_block.offset().left, 
                        width: beginning_block.outerWidth(), 
                        height:end_block.offset().top-beginning_block.offset().top+end_offset, 
                        background:'red'});
        });
    });
},

init: function() {
    this._super();
    $(window).bind('resize', $.proxy(this.updateCalendar, this));
},

willDestroy: function() {
    this._super();
    $(window).unbind('resize');
}
```

});

With this appoach it shouldn't be neccessary to look out for promises to fulfill (?). On the other hand, this is the only reason I can think of why this is not working.
(Note: On manually resizing the window everything works fine. Just the initial rendering makes trouble to me.)
What event do I actually have to listen to get this working?

### Edit

Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm using the ArrayController and the view is the container for the array elements.
Structure is thus:

```
 -Calendar (ArrayController, View with afterRender event)
 -Day (Item of Calendar, does not have a view - uses calendar view/template to be displayed)
```

The relevant part of the calendar.hbs-template is:

```
{{#each}}
    {{#each appointment in appointments}}
         <div class="appointment" {{bind-attr data-appointment="appointment.id"}}>{{appointment.title}}</div>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The model of Calendar is just requesting the days (part of CalendarRoute)

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return this.store.find('Day');
},
});
```

The day-model itself:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
date: DS.attr('string'),
appointments: DS.hasMany('Appointment', {
    async: true,
    inverse: null
}),
employees: DS.hasMany('Employee', {
    async: true,
    inverse: null
}),
opening: DS.attr('number'),
closing: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Appointment model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
title:  DS.attr('string'),
comment: DS.attr('string'),
doneBy: DS.belongsTo('Employee'),
beginning: DS.attr('number'),
end: DS.attr('number')
});
```

The day-model is backed by a controller but which does not contain any relevant stuff (only a computed field to create the timeslots based on the opening and closing hours from the day model).

### Edit 2

I updated all source codes. If you want to know how this looks like then visit http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ (week-view). Instead of different days I have the employees on the y-axis. There is no drag-and-drop planned, thus I only use tiemslots of full hours (instead of 30 minutes).

Comment: Will you show your template, and your model that backs the template (possibly the route and controller as well)

Comment: I edited my first post. As mentioned above maybe I should have said that I use the ArrayController...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I finally figured out a few days ago how to solve this problem. In this source (http://yoranbrondsema.com/loading-animations-asynchronous-models-ember-js/) it is decribed exactly what I was looking for but for a slightly different use case. Even though the solution to their use case might not be the best (as mentioned in their comments better use the loading route if that is possible). However, I could just use the code for exactly my setup. The critical part is the hasMany-relation in my data with async-loading. So all I had to do is run my jQuery-code after the hasMany-relation resolves and then after the next rendering my code is called:

**CalendarRoute**

```
setupController: function(controller, day) {
    this._super(controller, day);
    // Pre-load the comments
    // The 'get' call will result in an AJAX call to get
    // the comments and returns a promise
    Ember.RSVP.makePromise = function(maybePromise) {
        // Test if it's a promise
        if (maybePromise.then) {
            // Then return it
            return maybePromise;
        } else {
            // Wrap it in a Promise that resolves directly
            return Ember.RSVP.resolve(maybePromise);
        }
    };
    var appointments = day.get('appointments');

    // Wait until the promise has been resolved
    appointments.then(function() { 
        // Wait until all templates have finished rendering
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
            // Here goes my jQuery code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Watching the length of an array in Ember is as simple as observing `property.[]`. You should never really have to watch the DOM like you're trying to do considering the JS is writing to the DOM!

### Part 1: Binding the position

I think a good, Emberish approach is to use an itemController for each item in your arrayController and bind a style attribute to `div.appointment` or whatever element it is that would want to reposition. The `style` property itself will be a computed property based on the data returned. Here is a simplified example:

Let's suppose the position of the element is somehow relative to the month.

```
App.CalendarController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'day'
});

App.DayController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  positioning: function() { 
    var top = 'top: ' + this.get('month') / 2 + 'px;';
    var left = 'left: ' + this.get('month') * 5 + 'px;';

    return top + left;
  }.property('month'),
});
```

And your template:

```
{{#each controller}}
  <div {{bind-attr style=positioning}}>{{title}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Alternatively, you could use a Em.ColectionView with an itemViewClass.

### Part 2: Recalculating on resize

As for the window resizing, utilizing percentage positioning might mean you don't have to watch for a resize and you can use position and negative percentage margins to shift the element relative to it's width (i.e. creating position movement relative to the window and/or element width with css). However, that's not a JS solution.

Instead, an Ember-based solution is to use the following method to trigger an event, debounce it (so you're not making excessive calls) and recalculate the property - **please note:** the following is not yet adapted to whatever way you decide to manage the views/controllers but the theory is correct and applicable. Again, here is a simplified example:

```
App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
  positionTrigger: false,
  
  watchForResize: function() {
    $(window).bind('resize', $.proxy(this.resize, this));
  }.on('didInsertElement'),
  
  resize: function() {
    // No repeat calls within 200ms
    Em.run.debounce(this, this.toggleProperty, 'positionTrigger', 200);
  },
  
  positioning: function() {
    // Whatever you want to do to the position here
    var top = 'top: ' + this.get('month') / 2 + 'px;';
    var left = 'left: ' + this.get('month') * 5 + 'px;';

    return top + left; // Updates style binding in template
  }.property('positionTrigger', 'month'),
});
```

**Please note:** The way in which you combine the two above methods can vary (e.g. utilizing itemViewClass on a collection or doing it all in the itemController) but you will be able to achieve what you want how you want by combining the methods from parts one and two.

Depending on the use case, you might just want to have an observer on the `positionTrigger` property that does something else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I really thought the first part may be the solution until I realized that it is not possible for me not to access the DOM because I need the position of other elements in the calculation. Again I updated the inital post. I realy hoped I would not need to make it as long as it is now. You can see now the full source code. I hope that prevents any further confusion on what I try to do. Anyway, I'll definitly use the second part!

Comment: No problem. But you have access to all of the data for all of the other sibling elements in the javascript. I don't really see why you'd need to be going to the DOM. If you're talking about positioning based on the height of other objects like the table header row, you can just tell the `positioning` property to watch a third property that sets the height like `propName: function() {return this.$().find('.header').height()}.property('month','positionTrigger').on('didInsertElement')`. However, a good css layout may be your savior.